# Como hacer una calculadora con eclipse 1.8

Tags: jframe

Estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora usando eclipse.
La calculadora que quiero crear es sólo para calcular los resultados de los puntos pivotes, todo esto quiero que aparezca en una ventana JFrame.

Como calcular los niveles de pivote del mercado del oro?
Ejemplo: precio más alto   1223.90 +
                 Precio más bajo  1180.15 
                 Precio de cierre   1215.60
  Acontinuacion despues de sumar estos tres valores automaticamente dividirlos por 3
Resultado = nivel de punto pivote  1206.55

Eso es todo una suma de 3 valores y dividirlos por tres.

Comment: Hola muy intereante y todo, pero ¿Y que has intentado? ¿En que te estas atorando?

Comment: Tienes que poner lo que llevas, Aquí no harán ese trabajo por ti, en StackOverflow te ayudamos cuando te atores, si quieres un proyecto de 0, contacta con un consultor.